# If statement stripping links to variables

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, dreamhost

When I print the img table variables at the top of the printout, it works fine, but when contained within an if statement (if there isn't an image, I don't want it to print an empty image tag), this seems stop them working and therefore it does print an empty image tag, any ideas why this is, and how to resolve this ?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    print '<div class="testimonial">';
    list ($id, $companyname, $testimonialcontent, $name, $imglink, $imgdes, $logo) = $row;
    print "<p>$logo</p>\n";
    print "<p>$imglink</p>\n";
    print "<p>$imgdes</p>\n";
    if ($logo == TRUE) {
    print "<img src='img/$imagelink' alt='$imagedes'>\n";
}
    else {   
}
    print "<h3>$companyname</h3>\n";
}
?>
```

At the moment here is the relevant HTML being printed

```
<div class="testimonial"><p>1</p>
<p>logo1.jpg</p>
<p>image of starbucks logo</p>
<img src='img/' alt=''>
<h3>Sky Television</h3>
```

Comment: In your query, you have WHERE img.logo = TRUE. There shouldn't be cases of not having an image because you wouldn't be selecting them.

Comment: There are other images available in this table, where img.logo = TRUE allows me to only select the logo images.

Comment: Is there any value stored if there is not an image for the specific record?

Comment: No, it would just be empty records I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't see anything being assigned to the **`$imagelink`** or **`$imagedes`** variables.

It looks like those variables are evaluating to empty (zero length) string in the context where they are referenced (the `print` statement).

The `if` condition is comparing a different variable, not either of those two variables referenced in the `print` statement.

I don't believe the `if` is "stripping links to variables"; I think the problem is that you haven't assigned anything to those variables.

Comment: AH! That's because I've chosen to use img and image, which is the exact problem, should only be using one.

Answer (score 0):

You've got

```
if(condition) {
    print image
} else {
}
```

Since your else clause is empty, NOTHING will get printed if the condition ends up being false.

Comment: thanks, that however is my intention, I'd like the image tag to disappear if there is no image available to show, so nothing would be printed. That is more relevant when I get my FULL OUTER JOIN to work, which will pull the records from both tables, even if one side is empty.

Comment: Then you should look at what's in your `$logo` value. you're doing a basic `== true` which will succeed if $logo contains ANY non-falsey-value. `'arglebargle' == true` would succeed.

Comment: Run a var_dump on what should be an empty $logo and see what it returns.